# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN) Received when creating NSDictionary with BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

I am trying to create a dictionary object with 3 elements, one of which is a BOOL value. I am receiving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN, address=0x5) where I store the BOOL as an object using [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: object, key, nil]

What is wrong with the following code:

```
- (void) retrieveAchievmentMetadata
{
[GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) {
     if (error != nil)
     {
         // Process the error.
     }
     if (descriptions != nil)
     {

         [self setAchievementDescriptions:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]]; 

         for (GKAchievementDescription *achievementDescription in descriptions) {

             NSDictionary *achievementData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [achievementDescription achievedDescription], @"Achieved Description",
                                              [achievementDescription maximumPoints], @"Maximum Points",
                                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], @"Level Is Completed", nil];

             [achievementDescriptions setObject:achievementData forKey:[achievementDescription identifier]];

         }
     }
 }];
```

}

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs on the line

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], @"Level Is Completed", nil];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the crash is `[achievementDescription maximumPoints]`, the `maximumPoints` property return an `NSInteger` not a `NSNumber` instance.

Change it to :
`[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[achievementDescription maximumPoints]], @"Maximum Points", ...`

Comment: You could also use the literal syntax: @([achievementDescription maximumPoints])

Comment: @jervine10 Yes, also.

Answer (score 1):

Since the literal syntax is mentioned: If you wrote

```
NSDictionary *achievementData = { 
    @"Achieved Description": achievementDescription.achievedDescription,
    @"Maximum Points": achievementDescription.maximumPoints, 
    @"Level Is Completed": @NO
};
```

then not only is it more readable, but the compiler would also tell you if you do stupid things like trying to put an integer into a dictionary.

Comment: perhaps, but this syntax doesn't work. Could you update this please?